# Need similar vertical and horizontal scroll bar behavior in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I don't have depth ReactJs knowledge to convert this design into ReactJs. I have written this in Jquery. Could anyone suggest to me how to achieve the same design in ReactJs? The left div which contains the topic for each row should be sticky when scrolling horizontally. I can’t use jquery library anymore. I need to implement in pure react using typescript or emotion 10 or both.

Thank you.

[JSFiddle link for this example](https://jsfiddle.net/txn3p2jq/)

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="sticky">
    <div>First1</div>
    <div>First2</div>
    <div>First3</div>
    <div>First4</div>
    <div>First5</div>
    <div>First6</div>
    <div>First7</div>
    <div>First8</div>
    <div>First9</div>
    <div>First10</div>
    <div>First11</div>
    <div>First12</div>
    <div>First13</div>
    <div>First14</div>
   </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div>row content</div>
      <div>row content</div>
      <div>row content</div>
      <div>row content</div>
      <div>row content</div>
      <div>row content</div>
      <div>row content</div>
      <div>row content</div>
      <div>row content</div>
      <div>row content</div>
      <div>row content</div>
      <div>row content</div>
      <div>row content</div>
      <div>row content</div>
    </div>
        <div class="content">
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
    </div>
        <div class="content">
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
      <div>row content1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.main {
  background-color:blue;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

.row {
  height: 50px;
  clear: both;
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sticky, .content {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sticky {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
}
.content{
  background-color: green;
}
```

**JQuery to achieve horizontal scrollbar as shown in fiddle:**

```
$('.main').scroll(function(){
    $(this).find('.sticky').css('left', $(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

Comment: Have you atleast tried something in react? If yes, please share the snippet for others to help.

Answer (score 0):

`js` file :

```
import $ from 'jquery';  
class Test extends React.Component {

      componentDidMount(){
        $('.main').scroll(function(){
        $(this).find('.sticky').css('left', $(this).scrollLeft());
        });
      }

      render() {
        return (<div className="main">
      <div className="row">
      <div className="sticky">
        <div>First1</div>
        <div>First2</div>
        <div>First3</div>
        <div>First4</div>
        <div>First5</div>
        <div>First6</div>
        <div>First7</div>
        <div>First8</div>
        <div>First9</div>
        <div>First10</div>
        <div>First11</div>
        <div>First12</div>
        <div>First13</div>
        <div>First14</div>
       </div>
        <div className="content">
          <div>row content</div>
          <div>row content</div>
          <div>row content</div>
          <div>row content</div>
          <div>row content</div>
          <div>row content</div>
          <div>row content</div>
          <div>row content</div>
          <div>row content</div>
          <div>row content</div>
          <div>row content</div>
          <div>row content</div>
          <div>row content</div>
          <div>row content</div>
        </div>
            <div className="content">
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
        </div>
            <div className="content">
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
          <div>row content1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>);
      }
    }

    React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

`css` file :

```
.main {
  background-color:blue;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

.row {
  height: 50px;
  clear: both;
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sticky, .content {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sticky {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
}
.content{
  background-color: green;
}
```

and  `html` file :

```
<div id="app">

 </app>
```

I hope this is useful for you :)

Comment: I wrote this in codepen try find this https://codepen.io/daryoshsetorg/pen/WNvEwLP

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. I don’t have jquery library anymore. I can’t use as well. I need to implement pure react using typescript or emotion 10. Thank you.

Comment: We need to bind onScroll event listener. Replace css(‘left’, $this.scrollLeft()) with equivalent. I am still trying to find this equivalent park of css.